# Insert na tabela deixando null o antigo registro

Tags: sql

Bom dia Gente!
Tenho o seguinte código abaixo, onde estou tentando salvar um valor de kg por dia, estou usando como o base o dia sem hora, no entanto ao setar o valor para um dia qualquer, ao mudar o dia e rodar novamente, ele seta o valor no dia novo, mas retorna para NULL o dia anterior. Se puderem me ajuda, é para uma tarefa do trabalho.

```
Insert into CompraDiariaBI (DiaCompra)
select top 1  convert (date,DtInc)DiaCompra from FFardosCompra where convert (date, DtInc)>='2020-04-22' and convert (date, DtInc)<='2020-04-22'  


update  CompraDiariaBI  set Matriz_CSul_KG= (select sum(coalesce(PesoFardo,0))
from FFardosCompra fc
inner join FClasseCompra ci on (ci.CodClasseCompra=fc.CodClasseCompra)
inner join FProdutor p  on (p.CodProd=fc.CodProd and p.CodFilial=1)
inner join FProdInstr pi on pi.CodProd=fc.CodProd and pi.CodSafra=18
inner join FSupInstrSafra sis with(nolock) on (sis.CodInstr = pi.CodInstr and p.CodProd = pi.CodProd and sis.CodSafra=18)
left join FCargaProd cp  on cp.CodCargaProd = fc.CodCargaProd 
where fc.CodSafra = 18 and ci.CodVar=10 and fc.Status='A' and fc.PesoTransf is null and sis.CodSupervisor=16 
and convert (date,fc.DtInc)>='2020-04-22' and convert (date, fc.DtInc)<='2020-04-22' and tmp.DiaCompra=convert (date,fc.DtInc))  from CompraDiariaBI tmp
```

Na imagem abaixo, eu rodei o scprit novamente mudando o dia, ele setou o valor para o dia 22 mas deixou NULL o valor do dia 21.

[image: valor]

Como posso resolver isso, visto que todo dia tera de ser inserido um novo valor, e os antigos devem ser mantidos?

Comment: Sem a estrutura fica difícil identificar. Mas você pode tentar isolar os problemas, fazendo primeiro o select inicial e checando se não retorna os dois dias. Você também deve utilizar o where no parametro de data com o sinal de igual, pois está comparando se a data inicial é maior ou igual a 2020-04-22 E TAMBÉM menor ou igual a 2020-04-22. Exemplo: **convert (date, fc.DtInc) == '2020-04-22'** apenas.

Comment: @flvrm92 qual estrutura você diz? usei somente igual, porem o problema permanece, estou usando where, tem algum lugar que ele esta faltando?

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar a seguinte query

```
DECLARE
@pesoFardo DECIMAL

Insert into CompraDiariaBI
    (DiaCompra)
select top 1
    fc.DtInc
from FFardosCompra as fc
where fc.DtInc = '2020-04-22'

select @pesoFardo = sum(coalesce(PesoFardo,0)
from FFardosCompra fc
    inner join FClasseCompra ci on ci.CodClasseCompra=fc.CodClasseCompra
    inner join FProdutor p on p.CodProd=fc.CodProd and p.CodFilial=1
    inner join FProdInstr pi on pi.CodProd=fc.CodProd and pi.CodSafra=18
    inner join FSupInstrSafra sis with(nolock) on (sis.CodInstr = pi.CodInstr and p.CodProd = pi.CodProd and sis.CodSafra=18)
    left join FCargaProd cp on cp.CodCargaProd = fc.CodCargaProd
where fc.CodSafra = 18 and ci.CodVar= 10 and fc.Status='A' and fc.PesoTransf is null and sis.CodSupervisor=16
    and fc.DtInc = '2020-04-22'


-- select @pesoFardo

update  CompraDiariaBI  set Matriz_CSul_KG = @pesoFardo where DiaCompra = '2020-04-22'
```

Descomente a penultima linha (-- select @pesoFardo) para checar se o resultado não esta null e faz sentido com o seu where.
Comente a última linha (-- ) para não realizar a alteração antes de ter certeza que esta atualizando somente um registro.

Aconselho utilizar sempre um campo chave (PK) para fazer a atualização dos valores nas tabelas, diminuindo assim o risco de atualizar registros que não devem ser atualizados.